# Pass keyvault variable to stage template azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

If I do the same thing but don't use a template so passing variables between 2 stages then it works and I can **echo "$(varFromStageA)"** but when I implement the same using a template the variable is blank.

**azure-pipeline.yaml**

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: JA
    steps:
    - task: AzureKeyVault@1
      displayName: 'Get Secret'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: "***********"
        KeyVaultName: "*****"
        SecretsFilter: '*'
        RunAsPreJob: true
    - script: |
        echo "This is job Foo."
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]$(MySecret)" 
      name: DetermineResult
    - script: echo $(DetermineResult.doThing)
      name: echovar
```

**my-pipeline-template.yaml**

```
parameters:
#source
  sourceAccountEndpoint: '******'
  sourceDatabaseName: '*****'
  sourceAccount: '****'
  sourceEnvironment: '******'


  - stage: DownloadScript
    displayName: migrata data
    dependsOn: A
    jobs:
    - job: Pull
      variables:
        varFromStageA: $[stageDependencies.A.DetermineResult.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'] ]
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      displayName: migrate

      steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: Powershell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo "$(varFromStageA)"
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=doThing;isOutput=true]$(MySecret)"` is potentially exposing a secret value **as plaintext** in the pipeline logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Jobs can access output variables from previous stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages)

The format of referencing variables between stages is as follows：

```
stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']
```

From your YAML Sample, stageName: A, JobName : JA.

So you need to define the variable in template with the following format:

```
varFromStageA: $[stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing']
```

Then the value of the variable can be passed.

Template example:

```
 stages:
  - stage: DownloadScript
    displayName: migrata data
    dependsOn: A
    jobs:
    - job: Pull
      variables:
        varFromStageA: $[stageDependencies.A.JA.outputs['DetermineResult.doThing'] ]
      pool:
        vmImage: windows-latest
      displayName: migrate

      steps:
      - checkout: self
      - task: Powershell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            echo "$(varFromStageA)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch

There's some documented examples - it might help.  However, why not just set a global variable in the yaml file (i.e. above the stages)?  It's not clear from your question why you can't do this.

If you can, something like this:

```html
variables:
  var1: newitem
  
stages:
  - stage: one
  
 etc
```

If that won't work, try these approaches:

https://arunksingh16.medium.com/azure-devops-share-variable-across-stages-9bca85abfe8a

https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/